# Is it possible to do an in-place upgrade from Windows Server 2000 to Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2000

I have a machine (virtual machine) running Windows 2000
For PCI compliance, this machine needs to be ugraded to 2003 or above.

I have mounted a Windows 2003 ISO file as the CD Drive in VMWare, however, when I go to run the Windows Setup, i get this error:

> windows setup does not support upgrading from Microsoft Windows 2000 advanced server to Microsoft Windows Server 2003

I need to upgrade this machine - 
Starting from scratch with a fresh / bare-metal box is going to be very difficult.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a licensing problem; you are using the wrong release of Windows Server 2003.

Windows 2000 Advanced Server can only be upgrade to Windows Server 2003 ***Enterprise Edition***, upgrading to the Standard one is not allowed.